Counting number of languages over a given alphabet
This is more of a complexity theory question, but the core of it is combinatorics: I am given the following question. Consider words of size n from the alphabet $\Sigma := \{0,1\}$, and let $L \subseteq \Sigma^n$ s.t. $|L| = n^{k+4}$ for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$. What is the number of distinct $L$?
What perplexes me is that I can really solve this using two different ways of thinking:

To store all the words I would need $n^{k+5}$ bits so it can be at most $2^{n^{k+5}}$
I pick $n^{k+4}$ words from a set of size $2^n$, so there should be $\binom{2^n}{n^{k+4}}$ languages.

This checks out, but so far, but I would think the latter grows much faster than the first one, since it is factorial in the size of $2^n$, but that argument is clearly wrong. Where am I going wrong? And what is a proper lower bound for 2. ? I would like to show that the number of languages is definitely larger than $2^{n^{k+4}}$, which is part of the exercise, how would I do that?
I hope the question is stated clearly but I am happy to comply to any formatting rules of StackExchange.
CCI

Are two $L$s "distinct" if they have at least one word different, or if they have no words in common?

I call $L$ and $L'$ distinct iff $\exists x . x \in L \wedge x \not \in L'$

OK, so at least one word different

Use these bounds (wikipedia reference)
$$
\frac{x^y}{y^y} \leq \binom{x}{y} < \frac{(x\cdot e)^y}{y^y}=x^y \left(\frac{e}{y}\right)^y.
$$
Upper bound gives
$$
\binom{2^n}{n^{k+4}} < 2^{nn^{k+4}} \left(\frac{e}{n^{k+4}}\right)^{n^{k+4}}
= 2^{n^{k+5}} \left(\frac{e}{n^{k+4}}\right)^{n^{k+4}}
$$
and when $n$ is large this is very much smaller than $2^{n^{k+5}}$ since $\frac{e}{n^{k+4}} < 1$.
On the other hand, the lower bound gives
$$
\binom{2^n}{n^{k+4}} \geq
\frac{2^{nn^{k+4}}}{n^{(k+4)n^{k+4}}}
= \frac{\left(2^{n^{k+4}}\right)^n}{n^{(k+4)n^{k+4}}}
= \frac{\left(2^{n^{k+4}}\right) \left(2^{n^{k+4}}\right)^{n-1}}{n^{(k+4)n^{k+4}}}
= 2^{n^{k+4}} \frac{ \left(2^{n^{k+4}}\right)^{n-1}}{n^{(k+4)n^{k+4}}}
= 2^{n^{k+4}} \frac{ \left(2^{n-1}\right)^{n^{k+4}}}{n^{(k+4)n^{k+4}}}
= 2^{n^{k+4}} \left(\frac{ 2^{n-1}}{n^{k+4}}\right)^{n^{k+4}}
>2^{n^{k+4}}
$$
because we can assume $2^n \geq 2n^{k+4}$.
